# yosemite Xcode 6.3.2 and older osx versions

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite

In osx 10.10 yosemite, if i create an application for mac osx with Xcode 6.3.2 can this app be runned in older osx versions ? for example snow leopard ?
thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can, just change the development target as long as it's >= OS X 10.6